# How make ScrollTop to element

Tags: jquery, element

I'm getting started in the jQuery code. And I have the next script:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 750 ) {
    $( ".navigator" ).fadeIn();
} else {
    console.log('there');
    $( ".navigator" ).fadeOut();
}
});
```

Is it possible to change the beginning of the script, using a DIV (for example) instead pixels? I want to activate this effect when the scroll arrives to an element.
Is this possible?

Comment: `$(element).offset().top`? or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: use `$(element).offset().top`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div id="place" style="width:150px;height:1050px;">adasdasdas

</div>

<div class="navigator" style="width:150px;height:150px;color:green;"> hi....</div>
<style>

#place {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%; 
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}

.navigator{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
</style>

<script>

var targetOffset = $("#place").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {
    $( ".navigator" ).fadeIn();
} else {  
    $( ".navigator" ).fadeOut();
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Suchit
But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Thanks again!
:)